# Optimize current code to fill columns cells faster

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm creating a script (chrome extension) where rows of a table of a website can be moved up or down by the click of a button. This works perfectly by changing the  parameter and reorder the rows based on the new  parameters.

The code shown below is used to fill the cells of a certain column of the table with the new order of the rows. So the new first row get the number '0', the 2nd row '1', etc.

The issue is that the script below does it perfectly, but is very slow.
Is there any way to increase the speed of filling the cells?

```
    if (test.getElementsByClassName("tr").length == 0) {
    var tr2 = test_otheruser.getElementsByClassName("tr"), l;
} else {
    var tr2 = test.getElementsByClassName("tr"), l;
}

for (k = 0; k < tr2.length; k++) {
    let form_control = tr2[k].getElementsByClassName("td"), m;
    //write number in reorder cell downwards
    form_control[Reorder_column].getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0].focus();
    const inputElement = form_control[Reorder_column].getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0];
    //document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'input value');
    inputElement.value = k;
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(
        new Event("input", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true })
    );
    form_control[Reorder_column].getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0].blur();
}
```

The code works, but the for loop containing the .focus(), document.execCommand, dispatchEvent and .blur() is slow. I tried several things like just updating .value, but the only way the website where I fill in the table via this chrome extension excepts data that is written by this particular order of selection, filling, de-selection.

Simple HTML markup:

Immediately reordering happens by the id attribute of the row class "tr".
The reordering is saved by filling in the Td cell. This is done with the .focus(), .insert, .blur() functions. This is the only way the website accepts filling in a cell. This is the part that is slow and I would like to make it faster. When the website is reopened, the new order can be determined immediately by the filled in (stored) numbers in the reorder column.

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="table" role="table" style="min-height: 1014px;">
    <div class="header" role="row">
        <div class="th grid-col-text">
            <div class="me-1">
                <div class="btn-grid ms-1 " role="button" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="grid-header">
                        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;"><span>User order</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="th grid-col-text" role="columnheader" draggable="true">
            <div class="me-1">
                <div class="btn-grid ms-1 " role="button" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="grid-header">
                        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;"><span>Reorder</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div role="row" tabindex="0" class="tr" id="0">
        <div class="td" role="presentation cell">
            [SVG buttons up & down here]
        </div>
        <div class="td" role="presentation cell">
            <div class="grid-cell-input-wrap">
                <div class="autowidth-input grid-cell-input"><span>[HERE THE NEW ORDER NUMBER]</span><input class="form-control user-input"
                        type="text" value="[HERE THE NEW ORDER NUMBER]"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="td empty" role="presentation cell" id="1">
            <div class="grid-cell-input-wrap">
                <div class="autowidth-input grid-cell-input"><span>*</span><input class="form-control" type="text"
                        value=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Detach the row and reinsert it at the new position within the DOM.

Comment: This way the new order is not saved by the website. Only by filling in the column the order can be re-shuffled upon loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can move tables rows around by inserting them at a new index within the table.

Here is an example that contains a function which adds some action buttons for moving a row up/down. I even added a "delete" action to spice things up.

```js
// Pass a table reference into the function
addRowControls(document.querySelector('table.band'));

function addRowControls(table) {
  // Insert an "Actions" column
  table.querySelector('thead tr').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<th>Actions</th>');
  
  // Insert the action buttons cells in the new column
  for (let row of table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')) {
    row.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <button data-action="move" data-direction="-1" aria-label="Move row up">⇧</button>
        <button data-action="move" data-direction="1" aria-label="Move row down">⇩</button>
        <button data-action="delete" aria-label="Delete row"></button>
      </td>
    `);
  }
  // Add the button click listener
  table.addEventListener('click', onClick);

  function onClick(event) {
    if (!event.target.dataset.action) {
      return; // Not an action
    }
    
    const row = event.target.closest('tr');
    
    switch (event.target.dataset.action) {
      case 'move':
        moveRow(row);
        break;
      case 'delete':
        deleteRow(row);
        break;
    }
  }
  
  function moveRow(row) {
    const tbody = row.closest('tbody');
    const direction = +event.target.dataset.direction;
    const oldIndex = getChildElementIndex(row);
    const newIndex = oldIndex + direction;

    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex > tbody.children.length - 1) {
      return; // Index out of bounds
    }

    const beforeIndex = direction > 0 ? newIndex + 1 : newIndex;
    tbody.insertBefore(row, tbody.children[beforeIndex]);
  }
  
  function deleteRow(row) {
    const name = row.querySelector('td').textContent;
    const performDelete = confirm(`Are you sure you want delete "${name}"?`)
  
    if (!performDelete) {
      console.log(`"${name}" was not deleted`);
      return;
    }
    
    row.remove();
    console.log(`"${name}" was deleted`);
  }

  function getChildElementIndex(node) {
    return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(node.parentNode.children, node);
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: thin solid #AAA;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

th {
  background: #DDD;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<table class="band">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Instruments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Lennon</td>
      <td>Vocals, Guitar, Keyboards</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul McCartney</td>
      <td>Vocals, Bass, Guitar, Keyboards</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>George Harrison</td>
      <td>Guitar, Vocals</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ringo Starr</td>
      <td>Drums, Vocals</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. However, the website where I reorder the rows does not save changes in the DOM. The website only saves the input in each cell. So upon loading the website, the table is reordered by the column.

Comment: @Kclemen could you provide a very basic example of the HTML markup?